# Run coroutine past viewModelScope lifecycle

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

I need to make sure a suspending function will be completed even if the `viewModel` is cleared.
For example, I have a button in my app that when clicked calls `viewModel.addItem(item)`, that function then calls the repository which does two things:

1. Inserts the item to the local database
2. Sends a request to an API to insert the item as well (and waits for the response to update the item).

I want to finish the activity after **step 1**, BUT still continue with step 2 even after the activity finishes (which also clears the `viewModel` of course, which will cancel the API request).

I want it to behave like this because if I'll just wait for both to complete **and** the user have a slow internet connection, it will probably timeout and make the user wait on this activity. Instead I feel like its a much better user experience to complete the task locally  (finish the activity and let him do other stuff in the app) and wait for the server's response to then sync what ever happened (of course if the task didn't complete at all, I'll have to sync it when the user will have a better internet connection, but that's off topic).

Currently I have something like this (which describes the bad scenario with the timeout):

Activity:

```
viewModel.addItemLiveData.observe(this) { success ->
     if(success) //Toast well done
     else //Something went wrong

     finish()
}

button.setOnClickListener {
     val item = ... //Collected from the UI
     viewModel.addItem(item)
}
```

ViewModel:

```
private val _addItemLiveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val addItemLiveData: LiveData<Boolean> = _addItemLiveData

fun addItem(item: Item) = viewModelScope.launch {
     val id = repository.addItem(item)
     _addItemLiveData.value = id > 0
}
```

Repository:

```
suspend fun addItem(item: Item) {
     val id = roomDao.insert(item)
     
     //This part needs to run after the viewModel's lifecycle
     val res = apiService.insert(item) //Wrapped in a convenient class to indicate Success or Error
     if(res is Resource.Success) {
          roomDao.update(res.value)
     }
}
```

(Some code is omitted for brevity)

I thought maybe I could perform a `GlobalScope.launch` somehow, but I read its not best practice to use it (and I'm still quite new to kotlin so I'm not even entirely sure how to do it).

Also, maybe I'm not approaching this problem correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a custom global `CoroutineScope`, perhaps one set up by your DI framework and injected into the repository. So, for example, [here I set up a `CoroutineScope` in Koin](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/-/blob/v2.2/T23-Arch/ToDo/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/todo/ToDoApp.kt#L19), and I inject that into [the repository](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/-/blob/v2.2/T23-Arch/ToDo/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/todo/repo/ToDoRepository.kt), which uses it for database I/O.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I used both your comment and @Arpit Shukla's answer! Unfortunately I don't have DI so I'll have to pass the applicationScope manually from the ViewModel. is ```getApplication<CustomApplication>().appScope``` ok to use?

Comment: "I don't have DI" -- FWIW, Koin is really easy to use. "is getApplication<CustomApplication>().applicationScope ok to use?" -- if you mean have an `applicationScope` on `CustomApplication`, yes. However, `getApplication()` is a method on `Activity`, and neither your repository nor your viewmodel should have a reference to an `Activity`. So, be careful about your `Context` use, such that you do not create a memory leak.

Comment: Great then, I'll read more about koin :). And what if my ViewModel is actually AndroidViewModel? Then I do have access to `getApplication` method.

Comment: That's fine! I keep forgetting that `AndroidViewModel` uses `getApplication()` too.

Comment: Great! cheers, thanks a lot for your assist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a coroutine scope tied to your application lifecycle.
If you are using dependency injection, you should inject this scope to your viewModel. If not, you can create a scope in your custom application class.

```kotlin
class MyCustomApplication: Application() {
    val applicationScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())
}

class MyViewModel(private val app: MyCustomApplication) { // provide an instance of your custom application to view model

    suspend fun addItem(item: Item) {
        val id = roomDao.insert(item)
        app.applicationScope.launch {
            val res = apiService.insert(item) //Wrapped in a convenient class to indicate Success or Error
            if(res is Resource.Success) {
                roomDao.update(res.value)
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

You can go through [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-patterns-for-work-that-shouldnt-be-cancelled-e26c40f142ad) article for more details.

Comment: 1. Yeah, everything will get cleared when application dies. 2. The `addItem` in repository will return after calling `roomDao.insert`. You can return that id to the viewModel and you api function will continue to run in the background. What did you mean by "without splitting the methods"? I didn't get that.

Comment: Never mind lol.. My bad. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`NonCancellable`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#run-non-cancellable-block) context to create a suspending block that won't be interrupted if job or scope gets canceled:

```
suspend fun addItem(item: Item) {
     val id = roomDao.insert(item)
     
     //This part needs to run after the viewModel's lifecycle
     withContext(NonCancellable) {
         val res = apiService.insert(item) //Wrapped in a convenient class to indicate Success or Error
         if(res is Resource.Success) {
              roomDao.update(res.value)
         }
     }
}
```